# Will the method counts not increase using Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, user-interface, methods, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

We are planning to use **Jetpack compose** for our new in-house apps.

But while checking the documentation, I found that new methods annotated with composable will be created to create UI.

So I was wondering, will this not significantly increase the **overall method counts** for the final build.

Comment: Why would it? In some scenarios (e.g., simple uses of `RecyclerView`), your method count might *decrease*.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you don use it in your business app. now, it is not stable. The android studio supports it on 4.0, and now the stable version is 3.5.

here is the document says

> Note: Jetpack Compose is currently in Developer Preview. The API surface is not yet finalized, and should not be used in production apps.

the way it is realized like `Flutter` and `react-native`. it only is the UI framework. it makes it easy to write UI in code. for the method counts, I think **it will increase.**

Comment: Actually it is inhouse app, we can change it when required. So no issue with that. 
for the method count increase, I too thought the same. 
And that only emphasizes that, we should use it only for a small-scale app.